# Customizing the Comments' Index and Show Pages in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I want to be able to edit the Comments' Index and Show Pages in ActiveAdmin. By default the Index Page shows 6 attributes: `resource_type`, `author_type`, `resource`, `author`, `body` and `created_at`. But I want to show only `resource`, `author`, `body` and `created_at`. Also I want to be able to edit the filter and the Show Page and choose which columns to show and which ones not.

What can I do?

Comment: Well that's a typical case of what have you tried? What you could try is reading the docs and find a solution and if you get stuck on something come back here.

Comment: @DennyMueller I already did that before making this question.